# Limitations of (non-lightfield) near-eye displays

Tags: optics

The answer to  [Is it possible to blur an image in such way that a person with sight problems could see it sharp?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661/is-it-possible-to-blur-an-image-in-such-way-that-a-person-with-sight-problems-co) suggest that you cannot present a "counter blurred" out-of-focus image such that it appears sharp on the retina. These considerations should also apply the near-eye displays.

In a way the answer suggests, that the best possible image you can present on the screen is the original unblurred image. I find this hard to believe and certainly not exhaustive. First, it is not clear how you measure the quality of the retina image. What if I am willing to sacrifice contrast for sharpness?

In any case, I am intersted in a mathematically sound explanation of the phenomenon and under what circumstances (all?) the original unblurred image creates the best possible image on the retina, or of there are alternatives and their properties.

Comment: I am wearing an anti-blur device called "spectacles" right now. It works great and is a hands on proof that the general statement that blur can't be compensated for is total nonsense. There is blur that can be compensated for (like optical images that are out of focus) and then there is blur that can not be fully compensated for (like scattering on fog or some other random scatterer). Can an ordinary screen change the focal plane of an eye? No. Can a holographic screen do it? Yes, of course, that's how a holographic screen produces 3d images, to begin with.

Comment: Spectacles are lightfield devices as they change the direction of light. This is not what I am after. Also I am not after unblurring an image. What I am looking for is creating a counter-blurred image which, when blurred, reproduces the original signal. As of now, it appears to me that this is a matter of deconvolution, but the details and limitations are still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  It has already been demonstrated that a lightfield display can be configured to "counter-blur" an image such that a person with a given visual refractive error (including higher-order aberrations) will see it correctly.  (And no one else will.)

http://graphics.berkeley.edu/papers/Huang-EFD-2014-08/

Comment: My question was about non-lightfield displays. With lightfield displays it is kind of obvious that such things are possible.